# How to store new .drl file to BRMS rule engine server?

Tags: jboss, drools, rules

I have scenario in my project to make dynamic rule and store it into brms rule server. I've try to using KieFileSystem to write my String object become drl file, but I still cannot store my rule into rule engine server when I open the Business Central.

Here is my code from my Java main class :

```
// I called my artifact repository from BRMS server
String url = "http://192.168.0.1:8080/business-central/maven2/com/test/1.0/test-1.0.jar";
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieRepository kr = ks.getRepository();
UrlResource urlResource = (UrlResource) ks.getResources().newUrlResource(url);

urlResource.setUsername("username");
urlResource.setPassword("password");
urlResource.setBasicAuthentication("enabled");

InputStream is = urlResource.getInputStream();
KieModule kModule = kr.addKieModule(ks.getResources().newInputStreamResource(is));

KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();
String rule = "package com.test; \n"
+ "rule \"rule_1\" \n"
+ "when \n"
+ "then \n"
+ "System.out.println(\"rule_1 fired\"); \n"
+ "end";
kfs.write("src/main/resources/rules/generatedRule.drl", rule);
KieBuilder kb = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs).setDependencies(kModule).buildAll();
```

When I run this program, I cannot find my generated rule in my rule directory project in Business Central.

Thank you